# cc_load_policy is not working againts video "RXH1ol5qp4I" in youtube ifram api

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('player', {
                height: '100%',
                width: '100%',
                videoId: videoId,
                playerVars: {
                    'cc_load_policy': 1,
                    'controls': 0,
                    'showinfo': 0
                },
                events: {
                    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });
}
```